# Search for a value in multiple columns and copy the entire row if found

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My master worksheet (SHEET 4) looks like this.There are 22 columns and 940 file names in COL A and COL J.below is just an example :)

```
   COL A                    COL B       COL C      COL D            COL E   

    value                   value       value      value         PHHG.HGBRANM.BRANCH.KSDS

 PHHG.HGDWAGT.EXT.ESDS      value       value      value           value
```

In (SHEET 3) where I have 184 file names

```
  COL A

  PHHG.HGBRANM.BRANCH.KSDS

  PHHG.HGDWAGT.EXT.ESDS

  and so on....
```

Now the condition is all the files in SHEET 3 is either present there in COL A or COL E.I want to search for each file name from SHEET 3 in COL A and COL E (SHEET4) and if found copy the entire row and paste it to SHEET 5.Now I did something like this

```
Sub Search_Files()
Dim MyCell, Rng As Range, i As Integer
Dim RowCount1, RowCount2, j As Integer , k As integer
Myfile As string
K = 1
For i = 2 To 186
      Myfile = Sheet3.Cells(i, 1)
      For j = 1 To 920
        If (Myfile = Sheet4.Cells(j, 5)) Or (Myfile = Sheet4.Cells(j, 1)) Then
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 1) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 1)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 2) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 2)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 3) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 3)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 4) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 4)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 5) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 5)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 6) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 6)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 7) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 7)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 8) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 8)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 9) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 9)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 10) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 10)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 11) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 11)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 12) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 12)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 13) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 13)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 14) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 14)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 15) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 15)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 16) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 16)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 17) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 17)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 18) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 18)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 19) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 19)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 20) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 20)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 21) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 21)
          Sheet5.Cells(K, 22) = Sheet4.Cells(j, 22)
          K = K + 1
        End If
      Next
      Next

 End Sub
```

Its giving me results but its simply copying every file from SHEET 4 and COPYING it to SHEET 5.I have 184 files in SHEET3 so SHEET5 should contain only 184 files but I am getting 1107 files.WHY??????

Answer (score 0):

I had to make some adjustments for your code to run. When I did, though, it copied only the matches:

```
Sub Search_Files()
Dim MyCell, Rng As Range, i As Integer
Dim RowCount1, RowCount2, j As Integer, k As Integer
Dim Myfile As String
k = 1
For i = 2 To 20
  Myfile = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).Value
  For j = 1 To 20
    If (Myfile = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 5).Value) Or (Myfile = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 1).Value) Then
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 1) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 1)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 2) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 2)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 3) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 3)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 4) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 4)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 5) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 5)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 6) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 6)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 7) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 7)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 8) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 8)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 9) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 9)
      Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 10) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 10)
      k = k + 1
    End If
  Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Sheet 3:

[image]

Sheet 4:

[image]

Sheet 5:

[image]

Though, if your goal is to copy the entire row, it might be simpler to substitute:

```
Sheets("Sheet4").Rows(j).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & k)
```

In place of the section with all of the lines like:

```
Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(k, 1) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(j, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you LIZA :) you are a life saver.But what did you change in my code??

Comment: Hi Subhra. Primarily, I changed all of the references you had that were like "Sheet5" to being like Sheets("Sheet5") because I got the error "Object Required." I'm not sure if possibly you had defined them somewhere else and that's why your code ran as it was. I also added the "Dim" before "Myfile As String" because I was getting the error "Statement invalid outside Type block."